# Galaxy S3 dropping DSLR camera via OTG APP Logs included

Tags: android

I am looking for any input on a problem we are having with the Galaxy S3 i9300 and our app.

We are using the Stock ICS and tested JB 4.11 from Samsung updater as well as the base code used on the Nexus 4. No matter which version we have the same issue.

Our app allows us to associate a key card with a Photo taken by a connected DSLR via an OTG cable and tags the image as well as transfer them over wireless. A Photographer uses the Android device to scan the key card, he then takes a picture of the person and the S3 transfers the image to an image processing server we created.

We have tested this on several Android devices including Verizon Samsung Galaxy Nexus with ICS, exus 7 as well as the ACER A110 and have no issues.

The issue on the S3 is that it works fine on the bulk transfer endpoint (transferring an image), but on the interrupt endpoint where we monitor for new data it doesn't like. On a Nexus we hit the interrupt 10 times a second no problem, this quickly kills the S3 though. Extending the timeout helps but does not fix. This only occurs on the S3 device and this is the most frustrating part as we did not see this issue in our initial testing and we are on site with 8 devices now and every time it drops the connection you must restart the S3.

When the USB shuts down and requires the device to be restarted before it will work again, this is logged over and over in five second intervals, even with the camera disconnected

```
D/UsbHostManager( 2190): onUEvent(device) :: action = remove, devtype = usb_interface, device = /proc/bus/usb/002/001, product =
1d6b/1/300, type = 9/0/0, interface = 9/0/0, devpath = /devices/platform/s5p-ohci/usb2/2-0:1.0
E/UsbHostManager( 2190): usbDeviceRemoved :: deviceName = /dev/bus/usb/002/001
D/UsbHostManager( 2190): onUEvent(device) :: action = remove, devtype = usb_interface, device = /proc/bus/usb/001/001, product =
1d6b/2/300, type = 9/0/0, interface = 9/0/0, devpath = /devices/platform/s5p-ehci/usb1/1-0:1.0
E/UsbHostManager( 2190): usbDeviceRemoved :: deviceName = /dev/bus/usb/001/001
D/UsbHostManager( 2190): onUEvent(device) :: action = add, devtype = usb_interface, device = /proc/bus/usb/001/001, product = 1d
6b/2/300, type = 9/0/0, interface = 9/0/0, devpath = /devices/platform/s5p-ehci/usb1/1-0:1.0
D/UsbHostManager( 2190): usbDeviceAdded : device :: /dev/bus/usb/001/001 [1d6bh:0002h] [09h,00h,00h] (Hub(Full speed Hub ))
W/UsbHostManager( 2190): /dev/bus/usb/001/001 is put on a blocklist [1d6bh:0002h:09h:00h:00h]
D/UsbHostManager( 2190): usbDeviceAdded : device :: /dev/bus/usb/002/001 [1d6bh:0001h] [09h,00h,00h] (Hub(Full speed Hub ))
W/UsbHostManager( 2190): /dev/bus/usb/002/001 is put on a blocklist [1d6bh:0001h:09h:00h:00h]
D/UsbHostManager( 2190): onUEvent(device) :: action = add, devtype = usb_interface, device = /proc/bus/usb/002/001, product = 1d
6b/1/300, type = 9/0/0, interface = 9/0/0, devpath = /devices/platform/s5p-ohci/usb2/2-0:1.0
```

We also have WIFI issues ONLY with the S3 where it cannot connect to the Cisco wireless installed throughout the location. Other Android devices connect without issue. The S3 is able to work with autonomous WAPs which is how we are testing now.

We also have a Mobile swiper attached to the S3 which works without issue. (ID-TECH Shuttle).

My developer is on site and Internet access is extremely limited. That is why I am posting this question. Please accept my apology in advance but we are looking for any ideas though the developer is convinced that it is an issue with the USB Hardware since everything else works with the same code and only the S3's have these two issues. He is quite experienced and spent more time then he had available on site with this issue.  We will have to find another device if we cannot determine these two issues. FYI the Cisco is running an older WISM but other Android devices connect without issue.

Also the GT-i9300 S3 is an international version.

We tested 8 individual GT-i9300 S3 devices and they all have the same issue.

Comment: Can you post a code sample, please?

Comment: The developer is traveling.  Once he returns I will ask him for a sample.

The fact that the S3 cannot connect to the Wifi as well is certainly an issue.  

Is there any difference between the Verizon S3 WIFI and the i9300 Wifi that you are aware of?  We hae not tested a Verizon S3 but I am wondering if the Intl i9300 is the only phone with these issues.